# Login Security block my IP address

Tags: 6, users

I installed the [Login Security](https://drupal.org/project/login_security) module to block IP address for more than 4 number of login attempts, but unfortunately my IP blocked.

I tried uninstall the module, but still my IP address blocked. How to remove ban for my IP address. It shows the message **Sorry, 00.000.00.00 has been banned.**

I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I uninstalled the module, I kept being banned. To remove the ban for a particular IP, I followed the following steps:

- Connected to the database
- Changed the *access* table; either  changing the status to 1 or deleting the row with  mask equal to '127.0.0.1' and type equal to 'host' works

I found the solution on [Sorry, 127.0.0.1 has been banned.](https://drupal.org/node/233293)